# I need to convert string to byte string but am unable to do so, please assist me

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

```
def application(environ,start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    html = '<html>\n' \
           '<body>\n' \
           '<div style="width: 100%; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">\n' \
           'mod wsgi Test Page\n' \
           '</div>\n' \
           '</body>\n' \
           '</html>\n'
    response_header = [('Content-type','text/html')]
    start_response(status,response_header)
    return [html]
```

This causes an error saying:
TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type str found

Comment: Use `b'...'` instead of `'...'` to create byte strings…

Comment: @ScottC `'foo' 'bar'` (also with escaped line breaks in between) is perfectly valid Python syntax for `'foobar'`.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: if some function expects `bytes` instead of `string` then use `.encode()` - ie. `status.encode()` or `html.encode()` - to make sure you can use `.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @furas In this case, where all strings are hardcoded, it'd be a lot easier to just use bytes literals instead…

Comment: @deceze in this single example bytes literals can be OK - but I expect OP's next step will be to add some external string to HTML - and this will need to use `.encode()` :)

Comment: Here is the full error llog entry: [Thu Oct 13 16:09:17.743490 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 2638] [client 127.0.0.1:47554] mod_wsgi (pid=2638): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/wsgy.py'.
[Thu Oct 13 16:09:17.743665 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 2638] [client 127.0.0.1:47554] TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type str found

Comment: Just to be certain, do I use the b'...' on every line of code or just the string that is to be displayed.  I tried that and still got an error: [Sat Oct 15 08:51:12.132246 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 2632] [client 127.0.0.1:59068]     start_response(status,response_header) [wsgi:error] [pid 2632] [client 127.0.0.1:59068] TypeError: expected unicode object, value of type bytes found

Comment: *Some* strings are apparently expected to be bytes and others strings. Reading the documentation for the functions you’re using should clear up which is supposed to be which.

Comment: After much experimenting, this worksdef application(environ,start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    html = '<html>\n' \
    '<body>\n' \
    '<div style="width: 100%; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">\n' 
    html= b'mod wsgi Test Page\n' 
    '</div>\n' \
    '</body>\n' \
    '</html>\n'
    response_header = [('Content-type','text/html')]
    start_response(status,response_header)
    return [html]

Comment: Note html= b'mod wsgi Test Page\n'  and removal of .\. from lines 5 an 6 also I corrected the indentation